# Inserting old record into other table before updating MySQL Triggers

Tags: mysql, triggers, insert

I'd like make a copy of old record in my database. I tried use trigger but there's something wrong.
I'm using MySQL Workbench so I post this code:

```
USE `secus_21`;
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER `tsm_tasks_BUPD` BEFORE UPDATE ON tsm_tasks FOR EACH ROW
INSERT INTO `tsm_tasks_history`
    ( `ID_task` , `ID_user` , `ID_project` , `name` , `add_time` , `comment` )
VALUES
    ( OLD.`ID` , OLD.`ID_user` , OLD.`ID_project` , OLD.`name` , NOW() , OLD.`comment` );
```

to update event, added new record, and tried change something. I didnt receive any error so i was sure that adding finished successfuly but in `tsm_tasks_history` table still have nothing.

Edit:

Here are all trigger statement

```
-- Full Trigger DDL Statements
-- Note: Only CREATE TRIGGER statements are allowed
DELIMITER $$

USE `secus_21`$$

CREATE TRIGGER `tsm_tasks_BUPD` BEFORE UPDATE ON tsm_tasks FOR EACH ROW
-- Edit trigger body code below this line. Do not edit lines above this one
INSERT INTO `tsm_tasks_history`
    ( `ID_task` , `ID_user` , `ID_project` , `name` , `add_time` , `comment` )
VALUES
    ( OLD.`ID` , OLD.`ID_user` , OLD.`ID_project` , OLD.`name` , NOW() , OLD.`comment` )

$$

CREATE TRIGGER `tsm_tasks_BDEL` BEFORE DELETE ON tsm_tasks FOR EACH ROW
-- Edit trigger body code below this line. Do not edit lines above this one
INSERT INTO `tsm_tasks_history`
    ( `ID_task` , `ID_user` , `ID_project` , `name` , `add_time` , `comment` )
VALUES
    ( OLD.`ID` , OLD.`ID_user` , OLD.`ID_project` , OLD.`name` , NOW() , OLD.`comment` )

$$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You changed the delimiter to `$$` but didn't finish creation of trigger with `$$`. So the statement didn't complete.

```
USE `secus_21`;
DELIMITER $$

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS tsm_tasks_BUPD;
CREATE TRIGGER `tsm_tasks_BUPD` BEFORE UPDATE ON tsm_tasks FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
INSERT INTO `tsm_tasks_history`
    ( `ID_task` , `ID_user` , `ID_project` , `name` , `add_time` , `comment` )
VALUES
    ( OLD.`ID` , OLD.`ID_user` , OLD.`ID_project` , OLD.`name` , NOW() , OLD.`comment` );
END $$

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS tsm_tasks_BDEL;
CREATE TRIGGER `tsm_tasks_BDEL` BEFORE DELETE ON tsm_tasks FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
INSERT INTO `tsm_tasks_history`
    ( `ID_task` , `ID_user` , `ID_project` , `name` , `add_time` , `comment` )
VALUES
    ( OLD.`ID` , OLD.`ID_user` , OLD.`ID_project` , OLD.`name` , NOW() , OLD.`comment` );
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: What does that mean? I just finished your statement with `$$`.

Comment: I didin't delete it. MySQL Workbench deleting it. I'm creating all in this and have problem

Comment: @vanzen I edited my answer again, now please just copy the code as is and execute it. Then everything should be fine. And again, I don't know what you mean with Workbench deleting it.

Comment: Okay, cool, didn't think it'd be necessary, cause it's just one statement in trigger, added it just to be sure :)